# How to let the user choose how many lines python prints?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a homework assignment and I need to make it so the user can choose the amount of lines is printed. This is my first time posted here so if I'm doing something incorrect please let me know. Thanks

```
def verse():
    print ("Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!")


def sing(animal, sound):
    verse()
    print ("And on the farm he had a ", animal + ", Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!")
    print ("With a", sound + ",", sound, "here and a" , sound + ",",sound + " there.")
    print ("Here a", sound + ", there a", sound + ", everyehere a",sound  + ",", sound + ".")
    verse()


def main():
    lines = input("Enter the amount of lines you would like to see:")
    #not sure what to put next
    sing("cow", "moo")
    print()
    sing("horse", "neigh")
    print()
    sing("pig", "oink")
    print()
    sing("goat","baa")
    print()
    sing("hen", "cluck")

main()
```

Comment: [99 bottles of beer](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-python-808.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along these lines:

```
def sing(lines):
    template='''
    Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
    And on the farm he had a {animal}
    Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
    With a {sound}, {sound} here and a {sound}, {sound} there.
    Here a, {sound}, there a, {sound}, everywhere a, {sound}, {sound}.
    Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!'''

    verses=[("cow", "moo"),
            ("horse", "neigh"),
            ("pig", "oink"),
            ("goat","baa"),
            ("hen", "cluck")]
    li=[]        
    for n in range(0,5):        
        li.append(template.format(animal=verses[n][0], sound=verses[n][1]))   

    song=''.join(li)
    return '\n'.join(song.splitlines()[0:lines+1])         

def main():
    lines = input("Enter the amount of lines you would like to see: ")
    print(sing(int(lines)))

main()
```

Comment: I need it so it types however many lines the user wants it to be. So the full program is 25 lines if the user put 1 I need the output to be     Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh! and stop with that one line.

Comment: OK -- I made that change.